# Why does FusedLoactionProvider.getLocationAvailability() return null (while it should not)?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In initiate my google play services client like this:

```
public class MyApplication  extends Application implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

    protected synchronized GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    }


    /* GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Google play services connected.");
        boolean isConnected = mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();    // - this is true
        boolean isLocAvailable = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLocationAvailability(mGoogleApiClient).isLocationAvailable();
        // this causes NullPointerException because getLocationAvailabality() returns null. WHY ????
        .
        .
        .
    }

}
```

Google Play Services library version is Rev.24.
Why is this null pointer eception occuring? Google API client is initialized, connected, everything is as it should be per documentation? WiFi connection exists...

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have this problem? It's working well in my app (tested on Moto X 2013) with Google Play Service Libary Rev 25

But I got `null` when I tested on the Genymotion emulator that already has Google Apps installed. I had to open some Google App like Google Maps to get Google Play Service updated. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLocationAvailability(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

> Note it's always possible for getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient) to
>   return null even when this method returns true (e.g. location settings
>   were disabled between calls).

So there are a number of reasons why you could be receiving null. My suggestion is that you check for permissions, and make sure that location permission is allowed, not only check for if GoogleClient is connected and location is available. You can use the following function.

```
public static boolean checkAppPermissions(Context context, String... strPermissions) {
    for (String permissions : strPermissions) {
        if (!FrameworkUtils.isStringEmpty(permissions)) {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissions);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can call it like this

```
checkAppPermissions(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
```